# How to determine the stand-alone potential of words

Tags: r, ratio

I'm working on a multimillion-token corpus of conversational speech trying to determine *how words differ in terms of being able to form a complete utterance by themselves*. To that end I've computed two frequency lists:

1. `F_standalone`: the frequency of how often a word did stand alone in the corpus.
2. `F_overall`: the frequency of the respective words overall in the corpus.

Basically, one should assume that a word's potential of forming a complete utterance by itself can be read off the **ratio** of `F_standalone` divided by `F_overall`. While this may make sense for many words it makes much less sense for words that are ultra rare in the corpus overall: you get a (maximum) ratio of 1 if a word that occurs just once in the whole corpus (of many million tokens) happens to occur as a stand-alone word.

A reproducible sample of the data I have is this:

```
mysample <- data.frame(
  Word = c("vesuvius", "cruel","pentonville","mortuary","yuck","bollocks","yeah","mm","pardon"),
  F_standalone = c(1,1,1,2,7,26,22875,11576,584),
  F_overall = c(1,35,2,3,58,140,60158,21954,877),
  Ratio = c(1.000000000,0.028571429,0.500000000,0.666666667,0.1206896552,0.18571429,0.3802487,0.5272843,0.6659065)
)

mysample
         Word F_standalone F_overall      Ratio
1    vesuvius            1         1 1.00000000
2       cruel            1        35 0.02857143
3 pentonville            1         2 0.50000000
4    mortuary            2         3 0.66666667
5        yuck            7        58 0.12068966
6    bollocks           26       140 0.18571429
7        yeah        22875     60158 0.38024870
8          mm        11576     21954 0.52728430
9      pardon          584       877 0.66590650
```

As can be seen form the sample, `vesuvius`occurs just once in either condition (as stand-alone and in the corpus as a whole) and thus has a ratio of `1`; `pentonville` occurs once as a stand-alone utterance but twice overall, yielding a ratio of `0.50000000`. On the other hand, words such as `yeah`, `mm`, or `pardon`have both high frequencies as stand alone items and overall and get ratios between 0.3. and 0.7.

Given the much higher observed frquencies, `yeah`, `mm`, and `pardon` seem to have a much higher capability of forming an utterance by themselves than `vesuvius` and `pentonville`. So the ratio surely is an unreliable metric. How can an item's capability of forming a complete utterance be determined more reliably and with more statistical rigor?

Answer (score 1):

You are facing a sparsity problem. You would benefit from smoothing. For example, you could add $C=10$ or $C=50$ to each `F_overall`. For example, if you use $C=50$, then "vesuvius" has probability $1/51 \approx 0.020$ and "bollocks" has probability $26/190 \approx 0.14$ to appear standalone in an utterance.

This scheme does not alter much the probability of overall frequent words, but it lowers the probability of overall rare words quite a lot, which is what you want.

See [additive smoothing on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing) for more information, interpretations, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would a Fisher's exact test be appropriate? If yes, with or without the additive smoothing?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea if and how significance tests work when you "modify" your data via smoothing... I was thinking only from a traditional NLP perspective, where you have i.e. some positive examples of "standalone" words. Based on that, you can smooth and then compute a threshold that selects all these words, which should generalize nicely.